# UK Visa after H-1B Petition Denied

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, applications, h1b-visas

My employer had applied for a H-1B visa back in FY2020. The Form I-129, Petition for Non-Immigrant worker visa was denied by the USCIS. So my application was refused at the USCIS, and not after an interview at the US Embassy / Consulate. Now I am applying for a U.K visa and one of the questions is "**For either the UK or any other country, have you ever been Refused a visa**". Should I answer this question with a YES or a NO?

The reason I ask this is because my US visa petition was denied by the USCIS and not the Consulate.  So does it qualify as a rejection for me, since it is not the case that I have been through the US H-1B visa interview and got rejected?

Appreciate any help I can get in this matter!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi US Visa are issued by US consulates, which are a part of the The Department of State. USCIS (part of the Department of Homeland Security) do NOT issue visas.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the visa is issued directly by the consulate or embassy (which in that capacity acts like a consulate) using information attained from among other USCIS. It's the same with most countries, maybe all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst obtaining an approved I-129 application is a require step for many US work visas, it is not in itself visa application in any sense of the word.

Without your I-129 being approved, you would have never progressed to the stage of actually applying for a visa (ie, filling out DS-160 and attending an interview at a US Consulate), and thus you were never refused a visa - as you never applied for one.  Thus you can safely answer "NO" for this question.

The I-129 is a form filled in by the potential employer to obtain permission to employee a foreign worker. That's very different to a visa application which would be submitted by the individual requesting permission to travel to the US.

Comment: of course the grounds under which the I-129 was applied may well lead to rejection of a UK visa, but that's another matter entirely.

Comment: Does that mean I have to mention the I-129 rejection in the UK visa? The I-129 was rejected due to the specialized knowledge clause back then (and I suspect stricter vetting at USCIS), but I am applying for a different type of job now.

Comment: No, you do NOT need to mention the I-129 refusal in any way.